# Migrate from Classic ASP to ASP.NET (VB)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, asp-classic

Having looked at the "Questions that may already have your answer" ... I think my quandary lies in a different place.

I have self-taught Classic ASP having been left an intranet site to take over, which I've done OK with.  But as we are part of a much larger organisation, they use ASP.NET which I'm reluctant to migrate to but I have no idea how long is left with Classic ASP in terms of it actually still working.

I've learnt to code using just Notepad++ no graphic designer (to be honest I much prefer straight-forward editing like that).

The majority of the pages I now create are fairly simple html pages with quite a lot of JQuery/Javascript handling the input/data retrieval.  My Classic ASP comes in when I'm outputting from SQL into JSON format for the JQuery to handle.  So currently most of my ASP stuff if just outputting JSON data.

Having looked at the Visual Studio package (and pretty much hating everything I see), is there a simpler way of just turning my ASP pages into compliant ASPX code without the need to rely on Visual Studio?  The overall issue here is that my front pages are complete and can be used standalone, just requiring the JSON data.

Comment: `is there a simpler way of just turning my ASP pages into compliant ASPX code` -- no. you need to rewrite your code/web site. perhaps will be needed to rewrite everything. ASP & ASP.NET has only common name, but inside they are completly different.

Comment: Or, how I like to put it, classic ASP and ASP.Net are about as similar as Java and JavaScript.

Comment: Moving from one to another will be less about syntax and more about semantics. They're very different beasts.

Comment: You can code asp.net in Notepad++ if you really want to, but VS makes it easier, as you'll discover when you get a better understanding of how asp.net works

Comment: As to classic asp support.  The use of ASP pages will be supported on Windows 8 for a minimum of 10 years from the Windows 8 release date.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2669020

Comment: Thanks everyone for your feedback, I think it's something I HAVE to do at some point, I'd be more inclined to try and use Notepad++ as I'm so used to it and prefer working by code versus Visual Studio (mainly as it looks like a right pain the backside to compile it each time...)

Comment: Just try it in Visual Studio.  It has all sorts of smarts built in to help you autocomplete code, check your syntax and other things.  You can even edit and debug (by attaching to the w3p process) the classic ASP code using Visual Studio.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind, ASP.net is designed to be compiled, there are options to avoid that, but it is not the regular workflow. Compliation is part of the VisualStudio workflow. Further more, you get the ability to find all references to object, variables etc by right clicking on them. I've come from the world of classic ASP, it will take a bit of getting used to but I wouldn't look back now. One last thing, consider C#, it seems to be used more than vb.net.